# Mesibo SDK : 1 to1 chat : Voice Notes feature Android

Tags: chat, voice, mesibo

How to enable the Voice Notes  between users in the 1 to 1 chat using Mesibo SDK Android. The reference documents dont have much clarity.https://mesibo.com/documentation/api/real-time-api/file-transfer/#stopfiletransfer

Answer (score 0):

voice notes are nothing but media files. Refer,

How to send and receive files https://mesibo.com/documentation/tutorials/get-started/file-transfer/